# Does factoring change the result?

Tags: calculus, limits

If $\frac{x^2-25}{x-5}$ equals to $x+5$ (after factoring),why when 5 is plugged_in the result is not the same?
 why is that? does factoring effect the end result ?

Comment: I feel like this is something you easily could have Googled. We expect users to show an attempt to resolve their questions on their own. Look up “removable discontinuity.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you factor and cancel, you are making a key assumption: that the denominator is not zero (we make this assumption every time we do division!). In other words,
$$
\frac{x^2 - 25}{x - 5} = \frac{(x+5)(x-5)}{(x-5)} = x+5
$$
is only valid if $x\neq 5$ to begin with.

Comment: i wrote the question wrong ,sorry about that

Comment: With the new question, one of the new factors and the result should be $x+5$.  That does not change the fact that the approach is correct.

Comment: Edited to reflect updated question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be x-5. If you plug in 5 however, the denominator becomes 5-5=0 which is undefined since you cannot divide by 0.

Comment: i wrote the question wrong ,sorry about that